# Kind Classification of Types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Benjamin Pierce's book on Types and Programming Languages he classifies the different kinds of types as follows:

1. `*` the kind of proper types (like `Bool` and `Bool -> Bool`)
2. `* -> *` the kind of type operators (i.e., functions from proper types
   to proper types)
3. `* -> * -> *` the kind of functions from proper types to type operators
   (i.e., two-argument operators)
4. `(* -> *) -> *` the kind of functions from type operators to proper types

If we consider the tuple `(1,2)`, if I query the type and kind of this in the Haskell GHCI I get:

```
Prelude> :t (1,2)
(1,2) :: (Num t1, Num t) => (t, t1)

Prelude> :k (,)
(,) :: * -> * -> *
```

I don't see how `* -> * -> *` falls into category 3 in his definition above. To my knowledge, `(,)` takes two proper types to produce another proper type, not as Pierce states which is a function from a proper type to a type operator.

I am probably not interpreting Pierce's categorisation properly. Please can someone expand category 3 using my 2-tuple example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kinds are curried just like types.

The type of `(,)` (the value constructor) is `a -> b -> (a, b)`.  The type of `(,) ()` is `b -> ((), b)`.  The type of `(,) () ()` is `((), ())`.

Kinds work exactly the same way.  The kind of `(,)` (the type constructor) is `* -> * -> *`. The kind of `(,) ()` is `* -> *`. That's exactly what Pierce is talking about.  (And of course, the kind of `(,) () ()` is `*`).

---

**Edit**

The fourth category is a type that looks like this:

```
newtype Fourth f = Fourth (f ())
```

The `Fourth` type constructor has kind `(* -> *) -> *`. It can take as an argument any type with kind `(* -> *)`, like `Maybe` or `[]`.  So types like `Fourth Maybe` or `Fourth []` have kind `*`.

Comment: @I.K. Ok, added an example for that.